# angular-material2 - textbox value overlaps with placeholder value

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-material2

The below code doesnot set textbox value properly if it is placed inside http. Textbox value is overlapping with placeholder value.

```
 this.http.get('tes.json')
  .map(response => response.json())
  .subscribe(result => {
    (<FormGroup>this.form)
        .setValue({food: "test", food1: '123123'}}, {onlySelf: true});
  });
```

here is the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/aKZZ9vLLykVSMf3oqFEg?p=preview and below image which demonstrates the issue

[image]

But works fine if we set formgroup value outside http like this.

```
(<FormGroup>this.form)
    .setValue({food: "test", food1: '123123'}}, {onlySelf: true});
```

Can someone let me know what is causing this issue??

Answer (score 0):

your `this` scope is not loading.

```
let _self = this;
this.http.get('tes.json')
  .map(response => response.json())
  .subscribe(result => {
    (<FormGroup>_self.form)
        .setValue({food: "test", food1: '123123'}}, {onlySelf: true});
  });
```

Comment: plunkr you have shared is not working. i dont think problem is with `this`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by the new `mdInput` implementation. There will be a fix in the next Release (**2.0.0-beta.2**).

You could...

- wait for it,
- grab the current master or
- go back to the old `<md-input>` element until the new version is released.

When you're interested in what caused this, [this pull request](https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/2455) should have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Still having this issue in beta.10 .

If i click in the one input in the form.. it fixes all the inputs in that form

... my workaround for now is calling click event for the input